# CA Rally: How can I get all features for a release on a specific date

Tags: extjs, rally, code-rally

I need to get a list of all Features that belonged to a specific Release on a specific date. I know basically how to use the lookback API and I can use it get the Release object for the specific date. The problem is the Release Object doesn't seem to contain a Children element. This is according to the [official documentation](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/objectModel.sp#Release).

So I tried pulling all of the features for the whole project in hopes of being able to filter by Release.ObjectID, but anytime I try to filter by Release.ObjectID the response is null. Not an empty array indicating no matching records but actual null. I have probably tried a dozen different ways.

This is how the code looks now, with all attempts to filter by Release.ObjectID removed. Can anyone point out how to get this done as part of the query, or am I going to have to load all of the features and then manually filter them?

```
_lookbackFeaturesByRelease: function(){
    var scope = this.getContext().getTimeboxScope()
    var ReleaseID = scope.record.raw.ObjectID;
    var ProjectID = this.getContext().getProject().ObjectID;


    this.snapshot = Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore', {
        autoLoad: true,
        limit: Infinity,
        params: [removeUnauthorizedSnapshots = 'true'],
        find: {
            _ProjectHierarchy: ProjectID,
            _TypeHierarchy: "PortfolioItem/Feature",
            __At: "2017-02-10T00:00:00Z"
        },
        fetch: ['ObjectID', 'Name', 'Release'],
        hydrate: ['Release'],
        listeners: {
            load: this._processlbR,
            scope: this
        } //End Listeners
    });//End snapshot create

},//End _lookbackRelease
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just add something like this to your find:

```
find: {
    Release: { '$in': [12345, 23456] }
}
```

Where 12345 and 23456 are the release objectid's that correspond to your selected release and releases in child projects.  You'll need to query wsapi to find all the release oids in your current project scope and pass those values.